# Lua nginx extracting destination path from POST header

Tags: nginx, file-upload, lua, upload

I am working on uploading files using nginx. I have installed openresty module to support ngx lua .While uploading files I need to change the upload_store variable to the path in the POST header received. So I am thinking of using lua to change upload_store directive value in nginx.conf. I am trying to get the Dst-Dir from header like below:

```
location /umtest {
            set $upload_store /mnt/share_marvel/uploaded_files;
            rewrite_by_lua '
                local header = ngx.req.raw_header()
                ngx.say("type header",header)
                dst_path_dir = #need to extract from header
                ngx.var.upload_store = dst_path_dir
                ngx.say("upload store path" ,ngx.var.upload_store)

             ';
```

Header received from ngx.req.raw_header() is

```
POST /umtest HTTP/1.1
Host: X.X.X.X:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Dst-Dir : "/path/to/upload"
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

How can I extract the value of Dst-Dir, so that i can set that value to upload_store? I am pretty new to lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to [ngx.req.get_headers()](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_headers), for example:

```
dst_path_dir = ngx.req.get_headers()["Dst-Dir"]
```